# ibase_query resulting in HEX string instead of XML String

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a query that is returning a HEX String instead of an XML String.
In Firebird (2.5) The field is defined as LONG.

Any idea, what can be causing this? 
When retrieving with a GUI (e.g.: FlySpeed) will retrieve the full XML String. but on PHP 7 will retrieve an HEX String.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebird doesn't have a type called `LONG`, which would mean you have a self-created domain called `LONG`. You need to show the actual code and DDL of the table(s) and domains involved.

Comment: My bad..the field type is XML_DATA_STRING...it seems a self-create domain as well right?

Comment: None of us knows anything about this domain. From Mark's comment :"You need to show the actual code and DDL of the table(s) and domains involved."

Comment: I don't have full access to the database...but i could find the definition for this domain (old docs): `CREATE DOMAIN XML_DATA_STRING AS
  BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT`

Comment: @pmoreira u can extract table definition using text-mode tools (isql) or firebird-targeting IDEs (like IBExpert, FlameRobin, etc). Or u can do it yourself querying system tables - https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-appx04-systables.html

Comment: also you do not show the statement in question. So all in all you say "i was playing a lottery and was expecting to win $1000 but only one $10. Explain me what is wrong in the lottery" - but how can we guess it ?

Comment: @Arioch'The - The statement is quite simple `SELECT MAIN_EVENT.ID,MAIN_EVENT.IMPORT,MAIN_EVENT.RESULT FROM MAIN_EVENT`. I will try to fetch the table definition and post it here. It's not that I want to share the info...it's just i couldn't fetch yet...I'm a bit in a dark with regards to access information.

Comment: @Arioch'The - This is the create statement, as i told before...it's a really simple table. `CREATE TABLE MAIN_EVENT (
  ID                        INT64 NOT NULL,
  IMPORT             XML_DATA_STRING,
  RESULT             XML_DATA_STRING,
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);`

Comment: @pmoreira please do not burry details deep inside the comments heap, edit the question to enhance it and add relevant info there.  PS: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq329/

Comment: what are values like `select max(CHAR_LENGTH(IMPORT)), max(OCTET_LENGTH(IMPORT)) from MAIN_EVENT` ? Also `AVG` instead of `MAX` and also `RESULT` instead of `IMPORT`. I an thinking of pre-casting `blob` to `varchar` (which is 32KB max) /// https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-string /// https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-conversion.html#fblangref25-dtyp-tbl-conversions

Comment: `HEX String instead` - same length or varying length ?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to retrieve all necessary fields as a text string.

```
while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($sth,IBASE_TEXT)) {
                $res[] = $row;
            }
```

Now the data is retrieved as a text string. 
Although the execution time is now longer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your blob field to this function

```
function bl($field) {
    $s = "";
    if ($field != null) {
        $blob_data = ibase_blob_info($field);
        $blob_hndl = ibase_blob_open($field);
        $s = ibase_blob_get($blob_hndl, $blob_data[0]);
        ibase_blob_close($blob_hndl);
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Comment: I will try that one as well...but that would increase the connection time on each server (i have to connect to 140+), right?And also increase the load on the other servers instead of the one grabbing the data, right?

Comment: @pmoreira blobs are anyway stored outside of the table, so that would always be an extra connection, whenever you are exposed to it or not. The only other way would be to convert the blob field to varchar(nn) in your query. But varchar fields are length constrained.